# get android.os.Build.SERIAL for emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

How to get the serial for the emulator? If I use android.os.Build.SERIAL this works for real devices, but not for emulators :-(
Contains "unknown" then - should be something like emulator-5554 - so I can use it in combination with "adb -s"

EDIT:
my use-case: I have UserAcceptanceTests running on multiple devices / emulators attached. If a test fails on some device I make a screen-shot and want to be able to pull this one automatically - to do so I need to pass the serial from the instrumentation so i can pull the screenshot via adb.

Comment: Deleted my answer.  Use case changes things greatly.  I'm still working on it, but I'm beginning to think it's not possible

Comment: Perhaps you could just have your host-side instrumention inform the device-side instrumentation of it's adb serial/address upon initiating connection.